# My iDevice have some performance issues with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Actually I have Some Issues with my App. I have a counter which decrease each `0.0001` second thanks to my `NSTimer`. The `counter` starts at `999` and my timer calls a method who only decrease my counter by `1`.

SO, here's my problem: When I execute my app on the simulator it run just fine but as soon as I test it on my iPad 2 the counter is terribly low ...

The iPad 2 is maybe not able to calculate as fast as I would so is anyone here would have an alternative ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the timer? Are you driving an animation (CADisplayLink is a better choice)? NSTimer resolution is only in the milliseconds (0.001 seconds.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think timers were designed to run at that speed... You can try using a background thread instead...

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    while (true) {

        // Wait for delay
        usleep(100);

        // If counter is displayed on the UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Increment
            ...

        }

        // If not on the UI, just increment here
        ...

    }

});
```

Comment: Hi jjv360, I actually never used this so may be you could go further if you want to. My counter is on my UI so I just need to put my, for example "counter--;" on dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() and It will be enough ?